# Проверка наличие столбца в таблице и множественный LIKE

Tags: php, sql

Использую такой подход - `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name LIKE 'column_name'`

Как сделать множественный LIKE ?

Comment: Выполните нормальный запрос в INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. И стройте там любые мыслимые критерии.

Comment: Имеется ввиду такой запрос `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.СOLUMNS`

Comment: @Akina чем плох запрос, который использую я ?

Comment: У Вас вообще не запрос, хоть и выполняется так же, как и запрос. Считайте `SHOW` встроенным макросом - увы, устаканившейся русскоязычной терминологии в общем нет... хотя ихняя документация чётко разделяет, что есть statement, есть query, и первое - не всегда второе.

Comment: Собственно из этого и проистекают синтаксические ограничения - не принимает макрос множественные условия. Да что условия - его даже как подзапрос использовать нельзя!